# Flutter : Google Login pop up wont appear to select an account

Tags: firebase, flutter, async-await, google-authentication, bloc

I've created a login screen where when user press on the login button it calls out an event LoginButtonOnPressedEvent.
Below is my onLoginButtonOnPressedEvent function in my LoginBloc class.

```
 Future<void> _onLoginButtonPressedEvent(
  LoginButtonPressedEvent event, Emitter<LoginScreenState> emit) async {
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
  GoogleSignInAccount? user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
  await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  emit(LoginScreenState(user: user));
  print("USER DETAILS  : ${user}");
}
```

and I'm triggering this event in my LoginScreen as below where RippleButton is a custom button I made.

```
RippleButton(
          onTap: () {
            context.read<LoginScreenBloc>().add(LoginButtonPressedEvent());
          },
        ),
```

when I tap on the button,the popup to select an account wont show,instead the screen becomes a bit dark and then go back to normal.

Below is the log related to calling the event

```
I/ContentCaptureHelper(30073): Setting logging level to OFF
I/flutter (30073): USER DETAILS  : null
I/et_schedule_ap(30073): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2871953(94MB) AllocSpace 
objects, 9(308KB) LOS objects, 87% free, 3450KB/27MB, paused 142us,42us total 104.801ms
W/et_schedule_ap(30073): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows 
from 171 to 100
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you "sign out" because it appear at first time but after that will appear if you already not signed in "sign out"

```
GoogleSignIn().signOut();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, and what worked for me is logging out just before trying to open the Google account selection popup again, which means my code looks like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _googleSignIn.signIn();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:-

```
Future<void> _onLoginButtonPressedEvent() async {
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  try {
    GoogleSignInAccount? result = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    name = result!.displayName;
    email = result.email;
    password = result.id;
     
    print(result);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To show the google sign in popup, just call `signOut()`

```
_googleSignIn.signOut();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).